# how to merge these two query into one

Tags: sql-server

i have a table with these columns :

[image]

all the column is nvarchar type .

when i run a query like this :

```
select vendor,SUM(cast(SuccessCalls as int)) as successCalls,
SUM(cast(TotalCalls as int)) as TotalCalls,
SUM(cast(TotalMins as decimal(18,2))) as TotalMins,
case when  SUM(cast(TotalCalls as decimal(18,2)))  = 0  then 0.0 else (SUM(cast(SuccessCalls as decimal(18,2))) /  SUM(cast(TotalCalls as decimal(18,2)))) end as ASR,
case when  SUM(cast(ACDSuccessCalls as decimal(18,2)))  = 0  then 0.0 else (SUM(cast(TotalMins as decimal(18,2))) /  SUM(cast(ACDSuccessCalls as decimal(18,2)))) end as ACD,
SUM(cast(Profix as decimal(18,2))) as profix
from InterfaceMeraAdReport_CAV
where FromTime >= '20140717134000' and ToTime <= '20140717135000'
 and Customer= '01.2136'   and Area in ('62811','62812','62813','62821','62822','62823','62852','62853') 
 and Vendor='22394'
group by vendor
```

i got a result of this :

[image]

if i slightly change the query 's  WHERE condition :

```
    select vendor,SUM(cast(SuccessCalls as int)) as successCalls,
SUM(cast(TotalCalls as int)) as TotalCalls,
SUM(cast(TotalMins as decimal(18,2))) as TotalMins,
case when  SUM(cast(TotalCalls as decimal(18,2)))  = 0  then 0.0 else (SUM(cast(SuccessCalls as decimal(18,2))) /  SUM(cast(TotalCalls as decimal(18,2)))) end as ASR,
case when  SUM(cast(ACDSuccessCalls as decimal(18,2)))  = 0  then 0.0 else (SUM(cast(TotalMins as decimal(18,2))) /  SUM(cast(ACDSuccessCalls as decimal(18,2)))) end as ACD,
SUM(cast(Profix as decimal(18,2))) as profix
from InterfaceMeraAdReport_CAV
where FromTime >= '20140717133000' and ToTime <= '20140717135000'
 and Customer= '01.2136'   and Area in ('62811','62812','62813','62821','62822','62823','62852','62853') 
 and Vendor='22394'
group by vendor
```

i will get a result like this one :

[image]

what i do not know is , can i merge above two query into one query and get a result which contain two  result rows?

Comment: You can `union` results together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as all columns are named and formated identically you can always use `UNION` which will join the resultsets together.

```
(
select vendor,SUM(cast(SuccessCalls as int)) as successCalls,
SUM(cast(TotalCalls as int)) as TotalCalls,
SUM(cast(TotalMins as decimal(18,2))) as TotalMins,
case when  SUM(cast(TotalCalls as decimal(18,2)))  = 0  then 0.0 else (SUM(cast(SuccessCalls as decimal(18,2))) /  SUM(cast(TotalCalls as decimal(18,2)))) end as ASR,
case when  SUM(cast(ACDSuccessCalls as decimal(18,2)))  = 0  then 0.0 else (SUM(cast(TotalMins as decimal(18,2))) /  SUM(cast(ACDSuccessCalls as decimal(18,2)))) end as ACD,
SUM(cast(Profix as decimal(18,2))) as profix
from InterfaceMeraAdReport_CAV
where FromTime >= '20140717134000' and ToTime <= '20140717135000'
 and Customer= '01.2136'   and Area in ('62811','62812','62813','62821','62822','62823','62852','62853') 
 and Vendor='22394'
group by vendor
)
UNION
(
select vendor,SUM(cast(SuccessCalls as int)) as successCalls,
SUM(cast(TotalCalls as int)) as TotalCalls,
SUM(cast(TotalMins as decimal(18,2))) as TotalMins,
case when  SUM(cast(TotalCalls as decimal(18,2)))  = 0  then 0.0 else (SUM(cast(SuccessCalls as decimal(18,2))) /  SUM(cast(TotalCalls as decimal(18,2)))) end as ASR,
case when  SUM(cast(ACDSuccessCalls as decimal(18,2)))  = 0  then 0.0 else (SUM(cast(TotalMins as decimal(18,2))) /  SUM(cast(ACDSuccessCalls as decimal(18,2)))) end as ACD,
SUM(cast(Profix as decimal(18,2))) as profix
from InterfaceMeraAdReport_CAV
where FromTime >= '20140717133000' and ToTime <= '20140717135000'
 and Customer= '01.2136'   and Area in ('62811','62812','62813','62821','62822','62823','62852','62853') 
 and Vendor='22394'
group by vendor
)
```

However you might want to consider adding an extra column to identify which resultset comes from which query.